# .show() not working on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm triggering a onchange event that i have on a textbox when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[id$=dpDeliveryDate]").each(function () {
       $(this).get(0).onchange();
   });
});
```

This gets fired correctly and is calling a function I have created.

If I put in alerts into this function it will alert on the page loading correctly. So I know its calling the function just fine! but does not do the rest of the commands in the function

Also if after the page loads I change the textbox value it also fires correctly this time doing all the commands correctly in the function..

THe function basically needs to do

```
 $(this).parent().next().next().show();
```

So I cannot work out why it works onchange but not when onchange is triggered from the document.load?

Comment: Have you checked your console to see if there are any errors?  seems like there might be if it's stopping execution mid-function

Comment: Please show us your `.change()` handler function.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(this).get(0).onchange();
```

to

```
$(this).change();
```

Comment: tried but doesn't work, As I said, I know the function is getting called just fine..

Comment: @Steve does 'this' still refer to the dom node by using the native onchange() rather than jQuery's change()?

Comment: If we are talking about simpler code, `$("input[id$=dpDeliveryDate]").change();` would suffice. But this does not solve the OP's problem, would have been fine as a comment.